# Do you roll once for hunters mark and hex?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, damage

Both *hex* and *hunter's mark* state

> extra 1d6 [necrotic for hex] damage to the target whenever you hit it with a weapon attack

Recently a player stated that this means you roll 1d6 at the start of concentration and add that damage whenever a weapon attack hits. For example a player casts the spell and rolls 1d6 getting a 3. The next couple of rounds they land 4 weapons attack they add 3 damage to each of these attacks. I recognize this usually doesn't matter but its important to their build so I thought to ask.

Comment: I've marked your question as a dupe because I think it has been asked before. This isn't a bad thing as this question might help others find that one. If that question doesn't answer it for you, please clarify for us how and why, and we'll see what needs to be done to help you.